# Mail for Blackberry's - multiple content attachments

Tags: java, spring, email

We'd like to send a single email which has "multiple contents" attached.  Scenario is that we'd like one content to be displayed if the email is read using a Blackberry and another content displayed if the email is read in a desktop email client.  (Blackberry content would be just text, other devices should read the HTML content instead)

I'm off to do some research, but I wondered if anyone could tell me if this just doesn't sound possible.

Muddled illustration

Mail
   content 1 = text/plain device=blackberry
   content 2 = text/html  device=everything else

We're deevloping using Java/Spring, not that that is relevant for the general question here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the multipart/alternative tag in the e-mail. In my version of the Blackberry software (this will vary) it attempts to open the e-mail in the html version with a menu option to get the plain text version.

It is a good practice in general with complex HTML e-mail and helpful for many e-mail clients, but you don't get the kind of fine grain control you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks- I guess I'll add the text attachment and see what options the Blackberry gives the user - I wonder if it would be possible to put a <a href="XXX">Text Version</a> link at the top of the mail.  The XXX would need to open the text attachment on the email reader rather than go to a server though.

Comment: I tried a couple of things:

i) I added a mutltipart message, text and html versions with the multipart alternative setting.  Result was that the blackberry displayed the html version after stripping out the html tags.  Fail.

ii) I added an inline attachment of the form <a href='cid:textReport'>Blackberry friendly version</a>.  BlackBerry does not understand the cid: tag.  Fail.

So I guess I am going to have to resort to two emails.

Comment: @ashbyp, Although the blackberry may display the e-mail poorly, it should have a menu option to get the plain text. That may or may not work for your use case.

Comment: Apparently our users are not capable of using the menu system on the BlackBerry - they are busy Traders, don't ya know...

The message must be there and beautifully formatted for them.

Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code in some way or other

```
File f = new File("e:\\mailFolder");
File[] attachments = f.listFiles();


Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

// Part two is attachment
for( int i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++ ) {
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
FileDataSource fileDataSource =new FileDataSource(attachments[i]);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachments[i].getName());
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [multipart/alternative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Alternative) subtype within multipart message.

You will **NOT** be able to dictate which part gets opened by what mail client, however - it's up to client to decide.

As far as implementation goes, take a look at [MimeMultipart](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html) to get you started. Spring email integration does not support `multipart/alternative` messages directly as far as I know.

Comment: Ok thanks, we actually want to force the blackberry to open the text version (end user request I'm afraid).  hmmm.